# Magento 2: FastSimpleImport Integrity constraint violation

Tags: magento2, sql, import-products, avs-fastsimpleimport

I'm trying to import some products with Firegento FastSimpleImport

https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2
https://github.com/firegento/FireGento_FastSimpleImport2_Demo

When I run the demo for configurable products the first Import works.

The second time i run the Demo i get an error:

> /var/www/src/htdocs$ bin/magento fastsimpleimportdemo:products:importconfigurable
>
> Import started
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`catalog_product_super_attribute_label`, CONSTRAINT `FK_309442281DF7784210ED82B2CC51E5D5` FOREIGN KEY (`product_super_attribute_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_super_attribute` (`p), query was: INSERT INTO` catalog_product_super_attribute `(`product_super_attribute_id`,`position`,`product_id`,`attribute_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` product_super_attribute_id `= VALUES(`product_super_attribute_id`),` position `= VALUES(`position`),` product_id `= VALUES(`product_id`),` attribute_id `= VALUES(`attribute_id`)
>
> 1: Begin data validation
>
> 2: The validation is complete.
>
> 3: Checked rows: 3, checked entities: 3, invalid rows: 0, total errors: 0
>
> 4: Import data validation is complete.
> Import finished. Elapsed time: 3.45s

I tried it with an different Shop and it worked the second time.
Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Might be  a bug. Wish Magento Version are you using? We see the same since an Upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.2.8

Comment: Are you using `append` or `add_update`  behavior? For us this error does not appear for `append`.

Comment: Hi did you solve this?

Comment: I have the same problem on Magento `2.4.5-p1`. Validation checks out, all green but the actual Import has this problem. If I manually delete the record in `catalog_product_super_attribute` on this product_id,attribute_id the import works, but obviously that's not a solution. The Exception message does mention a `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` that should handle this, but it's not working.